# What open-source QR Code Generator would you recommend?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, qr-code

I'm looking for a library to generate QR codes in .NET I've stumbled across a few paid ones, but very few free ones that look any good. Anyone have experience with a good free open-source library?

Thanks

Comment: He's not asking what the best one is, he's just asking for recommendations.  I think it's valid.

Comment: @Jack Marchetti - it falls under "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: "I use ______ for ______, what do you use?" from the faq

Comment: @Daniel - I'm not using any framework at the moment. I'm trying to find one to use.

Comment: @Micah I tried [this](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/) just now. it's the best(easy to use and not complicated)

Comment: https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder

Comment: Question has also been [asked on CodeReview.StackExchange.com](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16794/1008) where it *is* on topic.

Answer (score 42):

Take a look at this one http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do you have any for .NET COMPACT FRAMEWORK?

Comment: Does it support Windows Store Apps ?

Answer (score 11):

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ and [How To Use ZXing C# Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655953/how-to-use-zxing-c-port) might answer your question.

Comment: Warning: zXing.NET doesn't support Medium Trust, meaning it won't work in ReportingServices (unless you have permission to change the trust level of SSRS).

Answer (score 7):

I have been using the other port [ZXing.Net](http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/) with some success. According to the website, it has assemblies available for the following platforms:

> - .Net 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0
> - Silverlight 4 and 5
> - Windows Phone 7.0, 7.1 and 8.0
> - Windows CE
> - Windows RT
> - Unity3D (.Net 2.0 built without System.Drawing reference)
> - Mono for Android

Comment: Warning: zXing.NET doesn't support Medium Trust, meaning it won't work in ReportingServices (unless you have permission to change the trust level of SSRS).

Answer (score 3):

In past I used [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/qrcode.aspx).
It's really "heavy" (about 6MB) but it worked for me and it's released under Code Project Open License (CPOL). I forgot: C# source code is provided.
Another one is [MessagingToolKit](http://twit88.com/platform/projects/show/messagingtoolkit), which is provided even with a free license; I don't remember (excuse me) if QR is inside free license or not.