# How to add "using Zxing" in source code?

Tags: c#, zxing

I am new to c#. currently I am trying to decode qr code via webcam, I have taken an example from the internet and re written it to try to understand the code. my question is How do I add using Zxing instead of using `com.google.zxing`?

I know that I should add a reference, but I try to add all the references I know but still it wouldnt allow me to add 'using Zxing'. it only allow 'using com.goggle.zxing' [ I use zxing.dll] as reference

Another problem is compiler error at `var reader = new BarcodeReader();` I belief its related to the 'using Zxing" or unknown reference

I really need help on this matter. Kindly show me how to solve or where can I find the Zxing reference. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you don't.

The library uses a namespace of `com.google.zxing`, so that's what you need to specify in the `using` directive. You don't get to change that namespace, unless you want to fetch the source code, change all the namespace declarations and rebuild. Why would you *want* to specify a different namespace in the `using` directive? What benefit do you think you'd achieve?

Of course you don't *have* to use a `using` directive at all. You could specify the full name of each type. For example:

```
com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader reader = new com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader();
```

But it would be much more sensible to use:

```
using com.google.zxing;

// Later in the code
MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
```

Comment: sir, i took the example from this page "https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/AForgeDemoForm.cs"

Comment: error 1 is Error =                                           1 The name 'LoadDevicesToCombobox' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\WeeJim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\New Folder\AForgeDemo\AForgeDemo\Form1.cs 78 10 AForgeDemo

Comment: error 2 is Error                                             2 The type or namespace name 'BarcodeReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\WeeJim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\New Folder\AForgeDemo\AForgeDemo\Form1.cs 159 27 AForgeDemo

Comment: the only thing that i couldnt re produce is the                          using Zxing;                                                          can this be the reason for the error. kindly advise

Comment: @WeeLeum: That's a different project! You can download the ZXing.Net library instead, but don't try to run examples from one project against the library from a different project.

Comment: sir , if based on this program "https://zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/AForgeDemoForm.cs"      do u mean "DecodeBarcode" is a stand alone project which the programmer add into "AForgeDemo"?

Comment: @WeeLeum: That code is a demo for `http://zxingnet.codeplex.com`, which is not the same project as `https://code.google.com/p/zxing/`. Decide which project you're using, and stick to it.

Comment: oh, thank you so much for highlighting it out.. looks like i was in the wrong direction all this while. thanks again sir. i appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655953/how-to-use-zxing-c-sharp-port) previous question should help you. Looks like `com.google.zxing` is the fully qualified namespace.

Try using that and checking if the objects and methods you require are present.

You could use and alias but why bother.

```
using zxing = com.google.zxing;
```

Comment: hai phil, thanks for replying. i appreciate it very much. sir, i took the example from this page "zxingnet.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Clients/AForgeDemo/.                i have re type the whole program and face 2 error                                                                              Error 1 is Error = 1 The name 'LoadDevicesToCombobox' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\WeeJim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\New Folder\AForgeDemo\AForgeDemo\Form1.cs 78 10 AForgeDemo

Comment: error 2 is                                                               Error  2 The type or namespace name 'BarcodeReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\WeeJim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\New Folder\AForgeDemo\AForgeDemo\Form1.cs 159 27 AForgeDemo

Comment: he only thing that i couldnt re produce is the using Zxing; can this be the reason for the error. kindly advise

Comment: Like Jon said in his post. Use the 'MultiFormatReader'. Lets face it Jon should know, he works for Google :-)

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. I take it you are using the ZXing.Net library from CodePlex and not the com.google.zxing?       Make sure you are using the correct DLL's from http://zxingnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes, mr phil. thanks for pointing out. now i know which direction i should go. thanks again. have a nice day.

Comment: hai mr phil, can gv advice on this matter - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328757/need-help-on-button-to-switch-on-webcam-for-c-sharp-based-qr-code-project

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line for namespace.

using ZXing;

after installing from nugget package.