# QR code - standard for developer

Tags: c#, java, oop, windows-phone-7, qr-code

where can I find features list for qr codes ?
I mean I can encode everything which can be represented by a string.

Example what I'm looking for:

SMS - "sms:text"

Email - "mailtio:text"

Text - "Text"

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? I'm confused.

Comment: QR Codes are for encoding data, do you want to know what a specific device supports?

Comment: String standard for QR codes. For example: for calender, Event, Network, Localization and more

Comment: You mean what features a QR code reader app can do?

Comment: Excacly, sorry for the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most devices support [MeCard](http://theqrplace.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/qr-code-tech-info-mecard-format/), Hyperlinks, Phone Numbers, Email Addresses, [vCards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350), some support Wifi Settings, and text display. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1655953/2970947) for how to use a ZXing C# API.

A MeCard is a semicolon and colon delimited set of fields and might look like this

```
MECARD:N:Elliott Frisch;URL:frischcode.com;
```

A hyperlink starts with a protocol followed by a colon, not every device supports every protocol. (e.g. `http:` or `ftp:` or `sms:` or `mailto"`).

Comment: But, I'm looking for string representation of these features.

Comment: Go read this [MeCard link](http://theqrplace.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/qr-code-tech-info-mecard-format/) - there's a few more examples there.

Comment: And here's a [vCard Class Library](http://www.thoughtproject.com/Libraries/vCard/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial will help you
http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/data-encoding/